TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile without an implementation for abstract method 'read'
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from app.database.requests import get_channels, get_subscribed_users, get_subscribed_user_ids, get_user_by_internal_id
from aiogram.types import InputFile
import os, io
import logging

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)  # или DEBUG для более подробного вывода

api_id = 'апи айди'          # Получите на my.telegram.org
api_hash = 'хэш'      # Получите на my.telegram.org
phone_number = 'фон'  # Ваш номер телефона для авторизации



# Создаем клиент Telethon
telethon_client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)



import logging

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)  # или DEBUG для более подробного вывода

async def setup_channel_handlers(channels, bot: Bot):
    for channel in channels:
        try:
            # Получаем объект канала по имени
            channel_entity = await telethon_client.get_entity(channel)
            logging.info(f"Отслеживаем канал: {channel_entity.title} (ID: {channel_entity.id})")

            @telethon_client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_entity))
            async def handler(event):
                logging.info(f"Новое сообщение получено в канале {event.chat_id}")

                # Проверяем, есть ли текст в сообщении
                message_text = event.message.text or ""
                logging.debug(f"Текст сообщения: {message_text}")

                # Проверяем, содержит ли сообщение изображение или другое медиа
                if event.message.media:
                    # Если есть медиа, скачиваем его
                    media_file = await event.message.download_media()
                    logging.info(f"Медиафайл скачан: {media_file}")
                        # Открываем файл и создаем поток
                    with open(media_file, 'rb') as file:
                        photo = InputFile(media_file, filename=os.path.basename(media_file))

                    logging.info(f"Готовим отправку фото: {media_file}")

                # Получаем название канала
                channel_name = event.chat.username or f"Channel ID: {event.chat_id}"
                logging.info(f"Название канала: {channel_name}")

                # Формируем текст с источником
                caption = f"\n\nИсточник: @{channel_name}" if event.chat.username else f"\n\nИсточник: {channel_name}"
                full_message = f"*Рассылка новостей*\n\n{message_text}{caption}" if message_text else caption
                logging.debug(f"Полное сообщение для отправки: {full_message}")

                # Получаем список пользователей, подписанных на канал
                subscribed_users = await get_subscribed_users(channel_tg_id=channel_entity.id)
                logging.info(f"Подписанные пользователи: {subscribed_users}")

                # Отправляем сообщение каждому пользователю
                for user in subscribed_users:
                    try:
                        if event.message.media:
                            # Если есть медиафайл, отправляем его вместе с текстом
                            await bot.send_photo(user.tg_id,photo, caption=full_message, parse_mode='Markdown')
                            logging.info(f"Медиафайл отправлен пользователю {user.tg_id}")
                        else:
                            # Если медиафайла нет, просто отправляем текст
                            await bot.send_message(user.tg_id, full_message, parse_mode='Markdown')
                            logging.info(f"Сообщение отправлено пользователю {user.tg_id}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Ошибка при отправке сообщения пользователю {user.tg_id}: {e}")

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Ошибка при получении объекта канала {channel}: {e}")







# Функция для запуска Telethon в фоновом режиме
async def start_telethon(session: AsyncSession, bot: Bot):
    # Запуск клиента Telethon
    await telethon_client.start(phone=phone_number)
    
    # Получаем список каналов из базы данных
    channels = await get_channels(session)
    
    # Настраиваем обработку сообщений для каждого канала
    await setup_channel_handlers(channels, bot)
    
    # Ожидание новых сообщений
    await telethon_client.run_until_disconnected()

нужна помощь, вкратце этот хэндлер ловит сообщения из других тг каналов и пересылает сообщения обратно юзеру в бота, проблема заключается в том что я хочу что бы бот пересылал также фотографии и др медиа файлы помимо текста, но когда тг канал приходит сообщение с фотографией или другим медиа фалом, он скачивает фотку и не пересылает говорит вот какую ошибку. Код написан на Aiogram, Python 3.12.6
 File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\bot\real_digest_bot\app\telethon_handlers.py", line 51, in handler
    photo = InputFile(media_file, filename=os.path.basename(media_file))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile without an implementation for abstract method 'read'


Ну там же написано в ошибке, что это абстрактный класс. Используйте одну из его конкретных реализаций, описанных в документации. Например, FSInputFile:
from aiogram.types.input_file import FSInputFile

photo = FSInputFile(media_file, filename=os.path.basename(media_file))


спасибо, проблема решена)

Кстати, непонятно, зачем вы файл открываете, переменная file там нигде не используется потом with open(media_file, 'rb') as file:

я просто новичек и выполняю один проект, учу всего 2 месяца и еще не сильно понимаю как работать с документацией. Вам большое спасибо я два дня потратил в поиске информации.
